# Как сделать толчок относительно самого обьекта

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, c#-7.3

Я делаю игру в Unity 3D, новичок. Хочу сделать толчок объекта, но локально, относительно объекта. То есть , например, толчок - вперёд будет туда куда смотрит объект. Его вращение происходит по физике и от столкновений. В интернете искал, но не смог найти решение. Буду рад если поможете.
Вот код:

```
public float MaxSpeed; // максимальная скорость

public WheelCollider WheelColliderPL;
public WheelCollider WheelColliderPP;
public WheelCollider WheelColliderZL;
public WheelCollider WheelColliderZP;

public Transform PLTransform;
public Transform PPTransform;
public Transform ZLTransform;
public Transform ZPTransform;

public GameObject PPL;
public GameObject PPP;

Vector3 TPL, TPP; // вектор поворота
private void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        count += 1;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * strike);
            count_2 = 0;
        }
        Debug.Log(count);
        if (count == 2)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * strike);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * strike);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.back * strike);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * strike);
            else
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * strike);
            Debug.Log(count);
        }
    }

    if (GroundTrigger.ground == 1 && count_2 == 0)
    {
        count = 0;
        count_2 = 1;

    }
}
```

Меня интересует вся часть с нажатием на кнопку space. Там я пытался сделать толчок с помощью направлений, но он всё равно происходит по глобальным осям, а не моего объекта.
Объект - рабочая машина с физикой.